How to REINDEX Postgres system index
I am trying to get all the data from a corrupted postgres db. I set zero_damaged_pages to on, and now I'm trying to connect to the DB, but I get this message:
connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL: index "pg_authid_rolname_index" contains unexpected zero page at block 0. Please REINDEX it.

How can I REINDEX it without connecting to the DB?
PG is inside a docker container.

For this specific problem, you can start PostgreSQL and tell it to ignore system indexes:

stop the server

start the server with
pg_ctl start --options=-P -D /path/to/data/directory



Then you should be able to connect and rebuild the indexes.
If you have corruption like that, the danger is that more than your indexes is broken, which will lead to further problems. But that would be a different question.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to be able to restart the server. I stop it with the <pg_ctl bin path> stop -D  -m smart. This logs me out of the docker container, when I enter again into the same container and run the above command (just changed pg_ctl to its bin), I get that "postmaster.pid" already exists and could not start server. Any suggestions?

Containerization is an additional obstacle here. You'll probably have to create a container that starts PostgreSQL like that. But really, when you have a cluster that is as corrupted as yours, you don't use containers, but access the data in the volumes directly. You'll probably have to hire a PostgreSQL forensics expert.
